# show-the-multiplication-of-two-functions

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $1\leq p\leq \infty$ and $q$ such that $1/p+1/q=1.$ Suppose $\mu$ is a positive σ-finite measure. Show that
if  $f\in L^p$  then  there is  $g\in L^q$  s.t   $fg\in L^1.$
converly if  $f\in L1$ then f=gh  s.t $g\in L^p$ and  $h\in L^q$

I have tried prove it and some techniques have been applied but unfortunately i could not do it.
any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: "I have tried prove" is not showing what you've tried. What have you tried? Hat techniques have you tried?

Comment: As stated this is pretty trivial ($g=0$ works). Is this really the question you wish to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g = |f|^{p-1}$, $|g|^q = |f|^{q(p-1)} = |f|^p$ and $|fg| = |f|^p$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take $g=|f|^{p-1}$ and apply Hölder's inequality.